# Overlay windows does not close using back button on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript

I found something weird. Desktop and mobile browsers do not work the same way regarding back button.

I have hamburger menu overlay, when I click it, it opens (absolute position DIV). When I click on the link inside this overlay, on desktop, it goes to the new page. Back button then brings the previous page back, WITHOUT the overlay. This is my expected behavior.

But as I've seen, on mobile (at least on Chrome, but I think on others also), when I have overlay open and click on a link, I get to the new page, but with back I get to the previous page with the overlay STILL OPEN. It would be kind of ok, IF clicking back again would close the overlay, but it doesn't. It goes to the page I was before clicking hamburger menu or exit site, if that was my first thing I did...

Now I can handle this in 2 ways:

1. I can close the overlay when clicking on a link inside the menu. When I did that, overlay closes and I get to the next page. Back gets me back to the previous page without overlay. So far so good, BUT... on desktop, when I click and get on a new page this way, I have to click back 2 times to come to previous page. So that is not good.
2. I can somehow make the back button to close the overlay first and the next back would go back one page, but that seems even more dirty than the first option handling the push states etc.

As I see many sites have solved this. On mobile, clicking on link inside hamburger menu (or some other "popup" with menus) gets to a new page and clicking back goes back to the previous page with hamburger closed. Same behavior is on desktop, no need for double back click.

Does anybody know how I should manage this and if anybody knows why mobile browsers do not close the overlay in the first place when clicking inside it or is there some easy setting that I could trigger this behavior?

Yours

Jerry

Comment: Is this your own custom code, or are you leveraging a library?  Can you include a [mcve] to show the issue?  Without accompanying code it will be difficult to assist you.

Comment: Thank you, it was more of a general observation how browsers work on mobile... I have my own custom code, I will try to make some minimal example somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you just discovered a browser feature called "bfcache". I have experienced similar issues once and it took me hours to figure out whats going on.

The implementation is inconsistent through out browsers (as well as their mobile & desktop versions) and background requests the page made. It requires a certain amount of page optimization if a consistent history back/forward behavior is needed. I'm not 100% sure if that's the problem here as you missing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you might want to investigate in that direction.

One of the best guides on how to handle back/forward caching is [this one from Google Developers](https://web.dev/bfcache/).

> **Back/forward cache** (or **bfcache**) is a browser optimization that enables instant back and forward navigation. It significantly improves the browsing experience for users—especially those with slower networks or devices.
>
> As web developers, it's critical to understand how to [optimize your pages for bfcache](https://web.dev/bfcache/) across all browsers, so your users can reap the benefits.
>
> The "cache" used by bfcache is different from the HTTP cache (which is also useful in speeding up repeat navigations). The bfcache is a snapshot of the entire page in memory (including the JavaScript heap), whereas the HTTP cache contains only the responses for previously made requests.
>
> – [web.dev](https://web.dev/bfcache/)

Comment: I will try to provide an example, but any overlay window with a link works that way. Yes, the back behavior is weird, it does not work the same all the time.